# MS DateTime only LOG table

Tags: sql-server, database, datetime

I am creating a database to store user information, and the changed made to the user will need to get logged.

This will eventually lead to a sort of 'timeline', so a Date / Time factor is crucial.

For this question, I will use the following example:

```
#ID - int
memName - string
memBio - string
memStatusString - string
```

Now, my though is to link that to a table as such:

```
ID - int
#memID - int
dateNameChanged - DateTime
dateBioChanged - DateTime
dateStatusStringChanged - DateTime
```

---

Is this a good way to log information? I want to do it on a different table to be easily able to list later.

Also, I never put the logging in the same table because the log date will only come after a change. IF the user never changes, it will just be a waste of space.

In conclusion;

Is there a better way to do this?

Update: I apologize for the lack of info.
I am using SQL Server 2008, asp net c# 3.5 - 4 (Only doing the database structure atm).

Also, a member will have different tables, such as tblMemberInformation, tblClanInformation, tblMemberGameRank

Each of the CHANGED data (Just to confirm) in each of the tables will need to be stored to a log file, with the corresponding date.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: You only want to log when something changed? Not the changed values (ie. `bioChangedFrom`)?

Comment: It would need to log both the item changed, and to what it was changed from -> to.

This is to have [user changed name to derp] - 03 May 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the version of SQL Server you are using, so I will assume a recent version.

SQL Server 2008+ has built in [audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx):

> Auditing an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine or an individual database involves tracking and logging events that occur on the Database Engine. SQL Server audit lets you create server audits, which can contain server audit specifications for server level events, and database audit specifications for database level events. Audited events can be written to the event logs or to audit files.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but as far as I can read, the Audit function will only work for databases, and not individual tables.
Furthermore, I only need to track select changes, not everything. :D

Comment: @NewAmbition - I believe you are mistaken. You can specify what tables to audit. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015.aspx).

Comment: I can see the process of the Audit function. Thank you for that. I am not a DBA, and I have never heard of the Audit function until now (Thanks again), but I see that it writes to a separate audit file on the disc... Will that not take longer to read/wright? I have learnt from my programming days to only really read/write to a DB.

Comment: @NewAmbition - Well, all databases have to store the data _somewhere_, right? I am just saying that in the end, even when using a db the data ends up on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :D I am in no way trying to debate your answer (I have not footing to do that), but as I said, I want to use as little space as possible, with the fastest process as possible. I want to get this right the first time (harder than threading a needle), so I need to make doubly sure that its all good :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Audit does allow you to audit specific operations on specific objects. For instance you can audit just UPDATE on one single table. See http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/sqlserver/auditpolicy/auditactiongroups/database-level_audit_actions.aspx. I realize SQL Audit may not fit this need but that is its capability.